# onStop is not being called when app is force killed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle

the ui was implemented using `jetpack-compose`. after i show `BottomSheet` somehow `onStop` is not being called when app is force killed from recent apps. but it is being called if there is no `BottomSheet`. any idea why?

Comment: This makes no sense. The app is not killable until `onStop()` is called and returns. Are you sure of this? How do you know? Is it crashing somewhere and you aren't recognizing this?

Comment: I assume you are referring to `Activity.onStop()`. Or are you referring to some other `onStop()` method?

Comment: @DavidWasser sorry for the delay. it happens for fragment's onStop

Comment: Is it possible that some method in the `BottomSheet` is being called in this case which causes the app to crash BEFORE `onStop()` of the `Fragment` gets called? Or are you doing something in `Activity.onStop()` that would prevent the `Fragment.onStop()` from being called in this case?